# Probability of existence of a path in a weighted probability graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, probability

So, I have a graph in which the edges either exist or they don't, and I have all the probabilities of whether each edge exists. I need to calculate the probability of whether any path between two specific vertices [A->B] exists, meaning a direct edge [AB] or an indirect one made up from more than one edge [AC, CB]. The number of vertices is finite and known.

Comment: How many vertices can there be?

Comment: The existence of an edge is conditioned to the existence of the previous edge. Learn about "Conditional Probability"

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

1. Run BFS to build an adjacency list with weight being the probability
2. Now run a modified "shortest path" algorithm. I put "shortest path" in quotes as we will run the longest path algorithm.
   2.1 Start from the end point, say B
   2.2 Now go back one step, this will be a list of elements. Say, B'
   2.3 Calculate the highest probability till all elements in B' and get max for going to B

   `D[i,j] = 0 if i = j and INF otherwise`
   [image: Rest of the algorithm]

Ref: http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~hzhang/c31/notes/ch06WGraph.pdf